# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404 in django chat application

Tags: django, redis, channel

```
<script>
    var roomName = {{ room_name_json }};
    console.log(window.location.host)
    var chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://' + window.location.host +
        '/ws/chat/' + roomName + '/');

    chatSocket.onopen = function(e) {
                                         alert("[open] Connection established");
                                         alert("Sending to server");
                                    };

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
                                             var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
                                             var message = data['message'];
                                             document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += (message + '\n');
                                       };

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
                                          console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
                                     };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').focus();

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e)
                                                    {
                                                          if (e.keyCode === 13)
                                                          {  // enter, return
                                                                document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
                                                          }
                                                    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e)
                                                {
                                                     var messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
                                                     var message = messageInputDom.value;
                                                     chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                                                          'message': message
                                                     }));

                                                     messageInputDom.value = '';
                                                };
    chatSocket.onerror = function(error) {
                                            alert(`[error] ${error.message}`);
                                         };
</script>
```

> I want to make a chat app so I am making use of Django channels and
>   Redis server.
>
> Error I got with it is given below
>
> (index):134 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/s/'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code:
>   404
>
> (index):150 Chat socket closed unexpectedly
>
> (index):167 WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.

routing.py in app

```
from django.urls import re_path

from .consumers import ChatConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', ChatConsumer),
]
```

routing.py in project

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import DjangoChatApplication.chat.routing as u

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            u.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Can anyone help me??

Comment: 404 is a Not Found error, so obviously the URL /ws/chat/s/ isn't defined anywhere in your routes. Showing us your script here is useless, you should show your routes.

Comment: Can you know tell me what might be the problem? Sir

Comment: I dont know if this solves your issue but `var roomName = {{ room_name_json }};` should probably be `var roomName = '{{ room_name_json }}';`

Comment: console your chatsocket variable before open.it should have one extra / i guess please check